# No module named 'structure' when installing PyBrain even though it's in the folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pybrain

I installed PyBrain via PyCharm and when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marcus/PycharmProjects/ANN/ann.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from structure.__init__ import *
ImportError: No module named 'structure'
```

However, in the folder site-packages\pybrain\ there's a folder named 'structure' with (what I assume is) what pybrain is asking for.

[image]

I'm pretty new to Python so I'm not completely used to this installing packages thing. Is it something that I missed? I have tried to search for a package named "structure" in the PyCharm package installer but there is none (only a 'structures').

Thanks in advance

EDIT: A comment asked me to further explain how I installed the package. In PyCharm, I went to project settings -> project interpreter -> search for "pybrain"

[image]

Comment: Please show *exactly* what you did to install that module. Note that the code for the module on Github shows `from pybrain.structure.__init__`, not `from structure...`, so something is weird.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Pybrain code here is *very* weird anyway and shows quite a large misunderstanding of Python modules: you don't import from `__init__`, you import from the package itself. No idea why they've done that, although it does seem to be consistent throughout the project.

Comment: Thank you. I added a screenshot of how I installed this module.

You seem to be onto something as the problem disappeared when I wrote pybrain.strucutre.__init__, however, this introduced similar errors in other files so I guess it's a problem with this installation

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem and tried all the suggestions mentioned here. Finally I realized that the version that was installing was 0.3.1, and it is not compatible with Python 3. So I deleted that version and then ran 
`!pip install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip`(from Spyder ipython console). This finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem.
I am working on Windows 8, 64 bit machine, with WinPython.

As every newbie would do. I install pip and then installed pybrain (or PyBrain, doesn't make difference).

After I tried to see if its working like this :

```
 import pybrain
```

I got an error saying :

```
There is no module named "Structures".
```

When I checked the site-packages, it was there.

I tried the following approaches :

1. I tried reinstalling Structures.
2. I tried using pip3 instead of pip.
3. I tried `pip3 install pybrain --upgrade`
4. I downloaded the .zip file of the entire project from github [here](https://github.com/pybrain) and after unzipping it, went inside it from cmd and did `python setup.py install`.

The **4th** approach worked like a charm.

Cheers.

Comment: @Rishika What is the problem you faced?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493217/pybrain-in-anaconda-importerror-no-module-named-structure ... Solves this problem by git installing pybrain...

Comment: This worked for me: `pip3 install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip` In my case was pip3, but if could be pip

Answer (score 2):

What I have done as following and it works. (windows 7, anaconda3 installed)

1. Download ZIP file from https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain
2. Extract the zip file and try `python setup.py install`
3. Open anaconda command and run `conda update conda`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: `pip3 install https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/archive/0.3.3.zip`
In my case was pip3, but it could be pip

Answer (score 1):

I would use pip (installed with 3.4) to install packages for 3.4+.  I used `pip install pybrain` (or maybe `... PyBrain`) last summer (for someone else) and the install worked with no problem.

What is a problem is that PyBrain is a 2.x package.  Fortunately, most of the incompatibilities are in the test suite (and those mostly due to using doctests).  The user I installed it for ran into a few easily fixed syntax errors and is still using PyBrain for a research project.