# PyBrain in Anaconda - ImportError: No module named 'structure'

Tags: python, package, anaconda, pybrain

I'm looking for a way to use numpy, scipy and pybrain in python. If I try to install those I get the error:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

I have installed visual studio but it still doesn't work.
I have tried setting up an environment with conda including numpy and scipy and then installing pybrain in it using pip but when I try to import it I get the error:

```
import pybrain
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\Anaconda3\envs\brain\lib\site-packages\pybrain\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from structure.__init__ import *
ImportError: No module named 'structure'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the library when used from Python 3 and installed using `pip`. The latest version [listed](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBrain) is 0.3.3, but I'm still getting v0.3.0 when installing.

Try installing `numpy` and `scipy` in Anaconda, then (after activating the conda environment) install directly from the git repo:

`pip install git+https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain.git@0.3.3`

This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

To solve you need to use:

```
pip install pybrain3
```